# PowerPoint 2013 email is opening in WordPad

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2013, wordpad

Can't get PowerPoint attachment to open. It opens in WordPad all the time. I accidently answered a question and said yes to opening in WordPad.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to open the attachment, Office (Outlook) should see it as PowerPoint and present both Open and Open in PowerPoint. I see that in Outlook here.

If not, go to File Association by File Type detailed settings and set .PPT AND .PPTX to PowerPoint. It may have been changed and needs to be changed back.

Assuming you make changes, close everything, restart and test again.

When this is done, if you still experience issues, you may need to reinstall Office and possibly even delete your Outlook Account profile and rebuild that.

Comment: Where is the file association?

Comment: It depends on your operating system. Detailed File associations may be in Control Panel. In later Windows 10, Start, Settings, Apps, right side, click on the link for File Association by file type.

Comment: thanks have managed to change back to powerpoint but still won't open in powerpoint?

Comment: I amended my answer. You may need to reinstall Office (restart between uninstall and reinstall) and also rebuild the Outlook Account profile (delete the profile, restart and make a new one). Also restart the computer if you changed File Associations.

Comment: Also make sure you change .PPTX  (PPT and PPTX are both PowerPoint extensions)

Answer (score 0):

Open a commmand prompt
Type "XXX" /REGSERVER
Substitute the actual path to your copy of POWERPNT.EXE in place of "XXX" above.
Surround the full path in quotes

It'll probably be:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\2013\Office15\POWERPNT.EXE"